Why is V8 anonymouse function context keeping unused variables?
I am debugging memory leaks in an Electron app with Chromium DevTools > Memory. The page uses DoJo dgrid and it has a class using event listener hooked on document object, see ColumnHider.js#L232. E.g. something like:
var activeGrid, bodyListener; // Global variables.

return declare(null, { // DoJo class definition (not important).
  // ...
  renderHeader: function () {
    var grid = this, ...; // These are kept in the listener context.
    // ...
    if (!bodyListener) {
       bodyListener = listen.pausable(document, 'mousedown', function (e) {
         activeGrid && activeGrid._toggleColumnHiderMenu(e); 
       });
       bodyListener.pause();
    }   
  }

When a grid is created and destroyed multiple times, DevTools > Memory snapshow shows a reference to the first instance is held by the var grid variable definition inside the renderHeader() method, i.e. bodyListener anonymous function context hold this reference even when it does not use it. (Note: the global variable activeGrid === null when I have taken the the memory snapshot.)
I always though JavaScript engine should keep used variables inside anonymous functions only in their context, so this kind of memory leak cannot occur. Or, is that influenced by DevTools somehow?

Do you have any other nested functions inside renderHeader that refer to grid? (In the snippet as posted, var grid is entirely unused, but surely that's not the case in your real code.)

What's the code in // ...? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8665781/about-closure-lexicalenvironment-and-gc, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24468713/javascript-closures-concerning-unreferenced-variables and more

@jmrk see the link ColumnHider.js#L232 I didn't post the whole code since it a bit long.

Also similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19798803/how-javascript-closures-are-garbage-collected
